# R: Determine redundancies and unique values in a set of columns

Tags: r, database, dataframe, redundancy

I'm hoping to determine when the values in a set of columns are redundant, documenting it in a new column `multi?` where 0 means only a single value is seen, 1 means multiple values are seen. When the value `"Unspecified"` is with other values, I'd like the code to ignore it and assess the redundancy of other values accordingly. When the value `"Unspecified"` is the only value in the set of columns, I would like the column `multi?` to document `"Unspecified"`.

Of note, these four columns are just a segment of a much larger database with many more columns.

To illustrate what I mean, I have provided an example input and output below:

```
  headbleed_type_dx1 headbleed_type_dx2 headbleed_type_dx3 headbleed_type_dx4
1      Intracerebral      Intracerebral      Intracerebral               <NA>      
2      Intracerebral      Subarachnoid                <NA>           Subdural      
3        Unspecified      Intracerebral           Subdural      Intracerebral      
4        Unspecified               <NA>                <NA>               <NA>               
5               <NA>               <NA>                <NA>               <NA>
```

If the row was 1 for `Multi?`, then I'd also like to document the number of unique values in the new column `Number`

```
  Multi?       Number
1 0            1
2 1            3
3 1            2
4 Unspecified  1
5 NA           NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really cumbersome and I would really advise against mixing numbers and characters in a column. Having said that and if you are open to a `dplyr` based solution

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarise(
    number = n_distinct(
      c_across(headbleed_type_dx1:headbleed_type_dx4), 
      na.rm = TRUE),
    unspec = coalesce(
      any(c_across(headbleed_type_dx1:headbleed_type_dx4) == "Unspecified"), 
      FALSE)) %>% 
  mutate(
    number2 = if_else(number > 1L & unspec, number - 1L, na_if(number, 0)),
    multi = case_when(number == 1 & unspec ~ "Unspecific",
                      number2 == 1 ~ "0",
                      is.na(number2) ~ NA_character_,
                      TRUE ~ "1"),
    .keep = "none") %>% 
  select(number = number2, multi)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  number multi     
   <int> <chr>     
1      1 0         
2      3 1         
3      2 1         
4      1 Unspecific
5     NA NA        
6      1 0
```

#### Data

```r
structure(list(headbleed_type_dx1 = c("Intracerebral", "Intracerebral", 
"Unspecified", "Unspecified", NA, "Intracerebral"), headbleed_type_dx2 = c("Intracerebral", 
"Subarachnoid", "Intracerebral", NA, NA, "Unspecified"), headbleed_type_dx3 = c("Intracerebral", 
NA, "Subdural", NA, NA, "Intracerebral"), headbleed_type_dx4 = c(NA, 
"Subdural", "Intracerebral", NA, NA, NA)), problems = structure(list(
    row = 1:4, col = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), expected = c("4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns"), actual = c("5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
    "5 columns"), file = c("literal data", "literal data", "literal data", 
    "literal data")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(headbleed_type_dx1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), headbleed_type_dx2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), headbleed_type_dx3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), headbleed_type_dx4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Right now, for rows such as this: 
"Intracerebral" "Unspecific" "Intracerebral" NA,
I am getting:
Number: 1; Multi: "Unspecific".
Is there a way to tweak the code so that it is: 
Number: 1; Multi: 0

Comment: That's indeed a bug.  See the updated answer.